# Best API for ISIN to name and vice versa

Tags: api, finance, rest

What is best API to lookup securities by ISINs ([International Securities Identification Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number)) or name?

In other words, ideally I would like to have an rest-api like this:

```
http://api.isinlookup.org/filter={"isin":"US38259P5089"} ->
[
  {
    "isin": "US38259P5089"
    "name": "Google Inc.",
    "type": "Equity"
  }
]

http://api.isinlookup.org/filter={"name":"Google"} ->
[
  {
    "isin": "US38259P5089"
    "name": "Google Inc.",
    "type": "Equity"
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: How many requests per day? Gratis?

Comment: I am not sure of the number of requests, more than 10, but less than 10.000. Free is better than paid, but I don't mind paying a modest fee.

Comment: I see you wrote `"type": "Equity"` in your example, is it a requirement, or is isin<->name enough?

Comment: It would be nice to have. I will need that information and it would be great if more info is given, especially when you just give a name. There will probably be thousands of results for "Google". It would help to have some hints to classify them. But, no, it's not a requirement.

Comment: This question was answered (even though closed) on StackOverflow back in 2009.  I would probably start there, assuming you don't just want to contact isin.org, who actually manage these mappings.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885456/stock-ticker-symbol-lookup-api